# Values of columns are getting interchanged after applying ColumnTransformer with SimpleImputer on my Dataframe

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, missing-data

I have a dataframe (xd) with mixed order of columns. example - categorical1, categorical2, numeric1, categorical3, numerical2, numerical3 and so on. now when I am using column transformer to use SimpleImputer the output is weird. In the output the values of columns are getting interchanged. for example -  numerical1 column now has values of categorical1 column, categorical3 column has values of numeric2 column and so on.

Missing Value per column:
[Missing values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcIOk.png)

[Dataframe xd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJPNb.png)
[Remaining cols of xd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfeJR.png)

```
numerical = xd.select_dtypes(exclude="object").columns
categorical = xd.select_dtypes(include="object").columns

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("impute1", SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent"), categorical),
        ("impute2", SimpleImputer(strategy="median"), numerical)
    ],
    remainder="passthrough"
)

X_transformed = preprocessor.fit_transform(xd)
f = pd.DataFrame(X_transformed, columns = xd.columns)
f.head(3)
```

[Output df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WMQx.png)
[Output df remaining cols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWfsg.png)

If you observe, the values of the columns are getting interchanged.
column KidneyDisease has values of column Smoker
column AlcoholDrinkers has values of column BMI
column BMI has values of column Sleephours
and so on.

I also tried explicitly specifying the columns:

```
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("impute1", SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent"), ['Sex','GeneralHealth','PhysicalActivities','Stroke','Asthma','SkinCancer','KidneyDisease','Diabetes','DifficultyWalking','Smoker','AgeCategory','AlcoholDrinkers']),
        ("impute2", SimpleImputer(strategy="median"), ['PhysicalHealth', 'MentalHealth', 'SleepHours', 'BMI'])
    ],
    remainder="passthrough"
)
transdorm = preprocessor.fit_transform(xd)
```

but i am still facing the same problem.

What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't create `f` dataframe with your original columns use `preprocessor.get_feature_names_out()` because columns are reordered ("categorical" first then "numerical" and finally "remainder"):

```
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("impute1", SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent"), categorical),
        ("impute2", SimpleImputer(strategy="median"), numerical)
    ],
    remainder="passthrough", verbose_feature_names_out=False  # <- avoid prefix
)

X_transformed = preprocessor.fit_transform(xd)
f = pd.DataFrame(X_transformed, columns=preprocessor.get_feature_names_out())
```

Comment: I am getting following error:

AttributeError: Transformer impute1 (type SimpleImputer) does not provide get_feature_names_out.

Comment: What is your version of `scikit-learn`?

Comment: The version is 1.0.2

Comment: Mine is 1.3.0. Upgrade your version of `sklearn` please.